# Recuperando o texto do EditText no AlertDialog

Tags: java, android

Boa tarde, estou com um problema... Ao clicar em um botão surge o alertDialog personalizado, ou seja contém um EditText nele e um botao **positive** para á conclusão. Só que eu preciso resgatar o text do editText para poder inserir no meu banco de dados e eu não estou conseguindo. Coloquei no **Log** não aparece nada, então eu fiz um debug, coloquei um breakpoint para ver se pelo menos estava resgatando um `getText()` e quando vou ver ele insere o valor como vazio **" "**

Não sei o que fazer, alguem poderia me dar uma ajuda? Fiz o getText().toString e nada de valor....

code:

```
private AlertDialog.Builder dialogs;
private String tsl;

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        golFora = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.golForaId);

        golFora.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                contador1++;
                valorDouble.setText("" + contador1);

                Context gol = getApplication();
                CharSequence texto = "Goooll!";
                int tempo = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                Toast apresentar = Toast.makeText(gol, texto, tempo);
                apresentar.show();

View vi = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.caixa_jogador_dialog, null);

                teset = (EditText) vi.findViewById(R.id.caixa_dialog_1);

                //criado só para o Log
                tsl = teset.getText().toString();

                dialogs = new AlertDialog.Builder(SimplesHome.this);
                dialogs.setPositiveButton("Sim", new 
                DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                     Log.i("CAMPOS", tsl);

                        Esporte s = new Esporte();
                        s.setJogadoresFora(teset.getText().toString());
                    }
                });

                dialogs.setView(vi);

                dialogs.create();
                dialogs.show();

            }
        });
```

Obrigado....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use o objecto Dialog passado ao método `onClick()` do DialogInterface.OnClickListener para obter a referência ao EditText:

```
dialogs.setPositiveButton("Sim", new 
DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

     Log.i("CAMPOS", tsl);

        EditText caixa_dialog_1 = (EditText) ((Dialog) dialog).findViewById(R.id.caixa_dialog_1);
        Esporte s = new Esporte();
        s.setJogadoresFora(caixa_dialog_1.getText().toString());
    }
});
```

Comment: opa... então o valor esta recuperado do editText esta sendo enviado como null para o banco...

Comment: Confira o código porque tem de funcionar. Verifique se o EditText é o `R.id.caixa_dialog_1` e que introduziu algo nele.

Comment: Desculpa, funcionou... o meu problema agora, não sei por que não está indo para o banco de dados, mas a recuperação do id do edit deu certo... Obrigado